# R Correlation of a selected vector variable in data.table

Tags: r, shiny, data.table, correlation

Correlation in R over a dataframe (df) returns error not subsettable.  Any suggestions are appreciated.  (I am new at this and have read all the posts here on correlation and data.table, along with the docs help on data.table)

```
VarCorr <- function(df, Y, Vars) {
  # Check data frame and formats
  if (!is.data.frame(df)){ # Check if data.frame
    return("Data is not a data.frame")
  } else if (is.numeric(Y)){ # Check if target variable is numeric
    return("Characteristic name not string")
  } else if (grepl("[.]",Y)){ # Check if there is a dot
    return("Name of a characteristic must not have a dot [.]")
  } else if (max(df[,Y],na.rm=T)!=1){
    return("Maximum not 1")
  } else if (min(df[,Y],na.rm=T)!=0){
    return("Minimum not 0")
  } else {
    # selected variable only
    SelVar <- as.vector(t(subset(Vars, Drop == 'N', select = var)))
    df1 <- subset(df, select = c(SelVar))
    # Drop dependent variable
    df1 <- df1[, !(names(df1) %in% Y)]
    SelVar <- names(df1)

# Here's my attempt at correlation of a variable within a data.table
     c <-  dcast.data.table[df, allow.cartesian=T][, cor(value, value)]

    return(df)
  }}
```

Returns the error:
Error in dcast.data.table[df, allow.cartesian = T] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Comment: dcast.data.table is not a variable of the script you show here.
Is it a function from a package you use? That would explain the error message: try with dcast.data.table(df, allow.cartesian = T)

Comment: example not reproducible